# How can you group successive dates to create a shorter string representing all the numbers in the list?

Tags: python, list, numbers

How can you group successive dates together into a a shorter string format such as the following:

```
date_list = ['2016-01-01', '2017-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-03', '2017-01-05']
```

I'd like to turn that date list into the following

```
desired_output = "1/1/16,1/1/17-1/3/17,1/1/17"
```

I've tried to implement solutions from here by using a function that calculates the difference between dates with little luck: [Identify groups of continuous numbers in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154249/identify-groups-of-continuous-numbers-in-a-list)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identify groups of continuous numbers in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154249/identify-groups-of-continuous-numbers-in-a-list)

Comment: Thanks - I tried to apply those solutions, but the challenge I ran into is that I'm actually dealing with dates, so I've updated my question

Comment: Same principle applies only you'll have to use `datetime` objects, most-likely

Comment: Right - that's what I thought as well, but it's not producing the correct groups. I can post what I've tried as well

Comment: Duplication question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768963/group-consecutive-dates-together-with-python

Comment: fair enough - that one does answer my question. I'll close. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group consecutive dates together with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768963/group-consecutive-dates-together-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

Before writing a script in python to do the task, let's see how we'd do this manually. Let's follow the given algorithm and see how it works.

> **Procedure**:
>
> **Step 0:** Take an empty string, named `output_string`.
>
> **Step 1:** Take an empty `sequence_list`.
>
> **Step 2:** Take the element (number) at the start of `number_list`, see if it can be added to `sequence_list`, then add the number to the `sequence_list` and remove it from `number_list`, and repeat **Step 2**. Otherwise, go to **Step 3**.
>
> **Step 3:** Compress `sequence_list` to a string, and add it to output.
>
> **Step 4:** If `number_list` is not empty, go to **Step 1** again. Otherwise, display the `output_string`.

Let's take one iteration over the list in question for example.

`number_list = [1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,18,19,40]`

**After Step 0:**

`output_string = ""`

**After Step 1:**

`sequence_list = []`

**After Step 2:** (Iterating 5 times)

```
sequence_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
number_list = [9,10,11,12,18,19,40]
```

Since, our next element is 9, which we can't add to the sequence list, we move to **Step 3**

**After Step 3**

```
output_string = "1-5"
number_list = [9,10,11,12,18,19,40]
```

**At Step 4**

Since, our `number_list` is not empty, we return to **Step 1**, and the whole process repeats for 3 more times. After which we get following `output_string`

`output_string = "1-5,9-12,18-19,40"`

This is the output we require. So, we are done.

Python Script for the same:

```
def numlist_string(numlist):
    # If the length of list is 1 then we don't need to write it in the 
    # form x-y, because that increases the number characters in string
    if(len(numlist) == 1):
        return "{}".format(numlist[0])
    else:
        numlist_last = len(numlist) - 1
        return "{}-{}".format(numlist[0], numlist[numlist_last])

def numlist_compress(numlist):
    if(len(numlist) == 0):
        return []

    compressed_list = []
    for i in range(len(numlist)):
        if(numlist[i] != numlist[0] + i):
            # Sequence is broken

            # Splitting up list into sequence and remaining
            req_list = numlist[0 : i]
            rem_list = numlist[i : ]

            # Getting sequence list as a string
            numlist_s = numlist_string(req_list)

            # Adding sequence string to the list of strings
            compressed_list.append(numlist_s)

            # Compressing the remaining list and adding that to previously 
            # generated sequence string
            compressed_list.extend(numlist_compress(rem_list))

            return compressed_list

    # Whole list is a sequence
    numlist_s = numlist_string(numlist)
    compressed_list.append(numlist_s)

    return compressed_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    number_list = [1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12,18,19,40]

    sequence_list = numlist_compress(number_list)

    sequence_string = ','.join(sequence_list) 

    print(sequence_string)
```